# Close Activity Using BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i have one activity Main.java is open in my application, i want to close the activity using broadcast receiver , how to close the activity?

Comment: i am asking about is there way to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly your Main.java needs to be registered as a receiver. You could register it in Main.java's onResume():

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BroadcasterClassName.NAME_OF_ACTION));
}
```

Then handle the broadcast and finish your activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(BroadcasterClassName.NAME_OF_ACTION)) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jack Sobremonte thanks for your answer, i accept your code but i have two java class file main.java is my activity and receiver.java is my broad cast receiver file then how i call the activity using the receiver class file...

Comment: Then your Main.java would need to extend Receiver, and Receiver.java will extend Activity

Comment: I ended up using a LocalBroadcastReceiver to get mine working. Check out the post that helped me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

Answer (score 0):

You could send a message to the activity which implements Handler.Callback, and handle it there to close the activity.

Quick example:

```
class Act1 extends Activity implements Handler.Callback {
 public static final int CLOSE_ACTIVITY = 54212;
 public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
   if(msg.what == CLOSE_ACTIVITY) {
    finish();
   }
 }
}
```

And then, since you BroadcastReceiver runs on main thread, in most of the cases. Just send the message via Handler.

```
new Handler().sendMessage(MessageFactory.createShutdownMsg()).
```

Comment: MessageFactory is not given in any package.

Comment: Please provide the implementation / library of `MessageFactory`

Answer (score -1):

you could do this:
in your main have:

```
private static Main mInstance;

onCreate()
{
   ...
   mInstance = this;
}

public static boolean closeActivity()
{
   if (mInstance != null)
   {
      mInstance.finish();
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

although, this implies only one Main exists at any one time. I think you can achieve that by adding android:noHistory="true" or something similar in the manifest.

Comment: how i call from broadcast receiver

Comment: Static reference to an activity will cause memory leak.